# Error getting json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have an javascript file that is meant to get the json file and if it's successful, it would perform a function and if it's not, it would show an alert window saying "error", but although the syntax looks correct, I am getting an alert window with error everytime.

these are the two files

```
var firstName = [];
var lastName = [];
var email = [];
var password = [];
var i;

function insertRecord() {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "studio.json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: insertData,
    error: function(){ alert("error"); }
});

function insertData(data) {
    if (localStorage) {
        for (i = 0; i < data.User.length; i++) {
            localStorage.setItem(firstName[i], data.User.firstName[j]);
            localStorage.setItem(lastName[i], data.User.lastName[j]);
            localStorage.setItem(email[i], data.User.email[j]);
            localStorage.setItem(password[i], data.User.password[j]);
        }

        localStorage.setItem(firstName[i], document.getElementById("firstName").value);
        localStorage[firstName[i]] = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
        localStorage.setItem(lastName[i], document.getElementById("lastName").value);
        localStorage[lastName[i]] = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
        localStorage.setItem(email[i], document.getElementById("email").value);
        localStorage[email[i]] = document.getElementById("email").value;
        localStorage.setItem(password[i], document.getElementById("password").value);
        localStorage[password[i]] = document.getElementById("password").value;

        alert(localstorage[firstName]);
    }

    else
        alert("Your browser does not support Local Storage");
}
```

}

The json file is called studio.json

```
{
    "Students":[
           { "first":"Arnold", "last":"Matthews", "class":"Tiny Tutus" },
           { "first":"Keesha", "last":"Franklin", "class":"Breakdancing"},
           { "first":"Dorothy", "last": "Ann", "class":"Acro"},
           { "first":"Wanda", "last": "Li", "class":"Ballet"},
           { "first":"Phoebe", "last": "Terese", "class":"Tap"}
    ],
    "Classes":[
        { "name":"Tiny Tutus", "time":"450","AMPM":"PM", "students":12},
        { "name":"Breakdancing", "time":"230","AMPM":"PM", "students":6},
        { "name":"Acro", "time":"810","AMPM":"AM", "students":15},
        { "name":"Tap", "time":"520","AMPM":"PM", "students":11},
        { "name":"Ballet", "time":"620","AMPM":"PM", "students":15},
        { "name":"Jazz", "time":"740","AMPM":"AM", "students":8 }
    ],
    "User":[
        {
        "firstName": "Michael",
        "lastName": "Jones",
        "username": "MJone",
        "email": "Michael.Jones@email.com",
        "password": "qwerty"
        },
        {
        "firstName": "Michelle",
        "lastName": "Lee",
        "username": "MLee",
        "email": "Michelle.Lee@gmail.com",
        "password": "asdfgh"
        },
        {
        "firstName": "Andrew",
        "lastName": "Bob",
        "username": "ABob",
        "email": "Andrew.Bob@hotmail.com",
        "password": "zxcvbn"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Why are you asking the same question multiple times? http://stackoverflow.com/q/15913912/218196 (deleted),  http://stackoverflow.com/q/15891809/218196

Comment: Oh, I realized that it doesn't even go into the localstorage. It crashes before it goes to the function. I've had to test on multiple computers

Comment: I don't think it's the same question.  Once is about parsing json, this one is about a jquery call.

Comment: @Steve: It's still the same problem though, getting this code work.

Comment: Sorry, I thought the problem was with the localstorage, not with getting the json file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know you could just store the JSON string, and then later parse it ?

```
function storeUser() {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "studio.json",
        dataType: "text"
    });
}

if ( ! localStorage.getItem('user') ) {
    storeUser().done(function(json) {
        user = JSON.parse( json );
        localStorage.setItem('user', json);
    });
}else{
    user = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('user') );
}
```

but you will have to wait for the async call to finish again !

MDN also has a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage) for localStorage, so it works for non-supportive browsers as well.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've tried that script and I don't know whether it works or not. Is it possible to add alerts in the function return $.ajax part?

Comment: The code works, if it works for you is impossible to answer. If you're using a browser like chrome, you can open the console and in the "resources" tab you can inspect the local storage, and delete data etc. when you are debugging stuff like this!

Comment: Thanks I think it should work, but I'm getting an error
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file location. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Comment: @Young-kyuQHan - That means you are violating javascripts [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), and you can't access content on external websites with javascript unless it's JSONP (which is not regular JSON) or CORS is enabled.

Comment: I've tried it and after trying on multiple computers, I got it to work.
Thank you very much

Comment: Oh I forgot, is it possible to append data into the local storage? As you can see in the json file, user has firstname, lastname, email, username, and password. Is it possible to append user input to the local storage? Thank you

Comment: @Young-kyuQHan - Yes, that's possible, but why would you do that when you can store the JSON string complete, and the later just parse it and have it available as an object you can access with dot notation.

Comment: Oh, you are right. I'm not all that familiar with json and storing them into string. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something called "debugging". Rewrite the `error` handler to take the arguments which jQuery passes to it, and then print them using console.log, or breakpoint it and inspect them in your debugger. Here is the signature for error:

> Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )
>
> A function to be called if the request fails. The
> function receives three arguments: The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x,
> XMLHttpRequest) object, a string describing the type of error that
> occurred and an optional exception object, if one occurred. Possible
> values for the second argument (besides null) are "timeout", "error",
> "abort", and "parsererror". When an HTTP error occurs, errorThrown
> receives the textual portion of the HTTP status, such as "Not Found"
> or "Internal Server Error."

Comment: That seems more complicated than I thought. So would I have to just substitute error: function() { alert("error") } with Type: Function(jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown)?

Comment: The point is that the error function takes three parameters. Place a breakpoint at the first line in the error function, and when it stops there, examine the value of `arguments`. Or, replace your error function with `error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){console.log (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);}` and see what is printed on the console.